# Hosting wordpress blog on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have hosted a wordpress blog on AWS using EC2 instance t1.micro (Ubuntu).

I am not an expert on linux administration. However, after going through few tutorials, I was able to manage to have wordpress successfully running.

I noticed a warning on AWS console that "In case if your EC2 instance terminates, you will lose your data including wordpress files and data stored by MySql service."

Does that mean I should use S3 service for storing data to avoid any accidental data loss? Or my data will remain safe in an EBS volume even if my EC2 instance terminates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the root volume of an EC2 instance will be deleted if the instance is terminated. It can only be terminated automatically if its running as a spot instance. Otherwise it can only be terminated if you do it.

Now with that in mind, EBS volumes are not failure proof. They have a small chance of failing. To recover from this, you should either create regular snapshots of your EBS volume, or back up the contents of your instance to s3 or other storage service.

Comment: Thanks for quick tip. I will go through tutorials on how to back up EBS to S3. I slogged through my console and nowhere it says my EC2 instance is a spot instance. So I guess I need not worry about it. I am using free tier currently and I am hoping to have not more than 5000 visits a month to my blog - which I am planning to use only to publish a few photography tutorial and not as an application having fancy functionalities. Under such scenario, I believe backing up my EBS volume to S3 on periodic bases should be good enough. Pl correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: All you need to do is create a volume snapshot to backup. Snapshots are stored on s3.

Comment: Sure. Will start using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup snspshot lifecycle policy to create scheduled volume snapshots.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html